# How to get the user's display name without getting a null check error in Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So, currently, I am creating a Flutter project which is an Android tricycle booking system. I am using a drawer widget inside the application. What I wanted to do is when a user logged in inside the application, their name will be shown in the drawer. However, when I tried following a tutorial video (since I am just a beginner), the screen always becomes red and shows the error:

```
"Null check operator used on a null value."
```

I think this is because of me trying to display the name of the user. Does anyone know how to fix this error? I am stuck already for so many days. Any help will be much appreciated!

**This is the snippet of my codes for fetching the user's name:**

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFFED90F),
                ),
                accountName: new Text(userModelCurrentInfo!.first_name! + " " + userModelCurrentInfo!.last_name!, // This is the line that makes it null
                style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),
                ),
                accountEmail: new Text(user.email!,
                style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),
                    ),
                currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/machu.jpg"),
                ),
              ),
```

**This is the code for reading the current user details:**

```
     static void readCurrentOnlineUserInfo() async
  {

    final FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? currentFirebaseUser;

    currentFirebaseUser = fAuth.currentUser;

    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref()
        .child("passengers")
        .child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid);

    userRef.once().then((snap)
    {
      if(snap.snapshot.value != null)
      {
        userModelCurrentInfo = UserModel.fromSnapshot(snap.snapshot);
        print("name" + userModelCurrentInfo!.first_name.toString());
        print("id" + userModelCurrentInfo!.id.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

**Another thing that I notice:**
*Upon logging in, it will show the null error, then when I go to another tab and come back to the page that says null error, it suddenly disappears. Why tho?*

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Added not null conditions

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFFED90F),
                ),
accountName: userModelCurrentInfo!.first_name !=null && userModelCurrentInfo!.last_name !=null ?
                new Text(userModelCurrentInfo!.first_name! + " " + userModelCurrentInfo!.last_name!, 
                style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),
                ):new Text('')// added null condition here, 
                accountEmail: new Text(user.email!,
                style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),
                    ),
                currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/machu.jpg"),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Hi! I have tried that already, yes it will somehow remove the error, but I think it's a bad user experience since the drawer will display an empty string on the user's login.

Comment: that's the error you asked for, and you need to debug why your method not working to retrieve username

Comment: That's what I'm asking for also. Can you help me with it?

Comment: can you check the google account you are using to login has username saved in it ?

Comment: Also can you check logs if there is any error in this method readCurrentOnlineUserInfo